# Convergence of the logarithmic integral $\int_{0.5}^1\frac 1{\ln(x)} \,dx$

Tags: analysis, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

I computed the integral using Wolfram Alpha, and it gave me values in terms of the logarithmic integral, but I am unsure on how to prove convergence or divergence using analysis. So I want to prove that the following integral is convergent.     $$\int_{0.5}^1\frac 1{\ln(x)} \,dx$$
My approach was to first let $f(x)=-\frac1{\ln x}$ and $g(x)=-\ln x$ .

Since they are both positive on $[0.5, 1]$, by the Limit Comparison Test, we have that $$\lim_{x\to{\infty}}\frac fg= \lim_{x\to{\infty}}\frac {\frac{-1}{\ln x}}{{-\ln x}}= \lim_{x\to{\infty}}\frac{1}{\ln^2x} = 0$$

Since $\lim_{x\to{\infty}}\frac fg= 0$, we have that if $\int g$ converges implies $\int f$ converges. Since $\int_{0.5}^1-\ln x\,dx\approx 0.1535$ it is convergent, hence $\int f $ also convergent.

Finally, since $\frac1{\ln x}\lt \frac{-1}{\ln x}$ for $x\in [0.5, 1]$ then $\int_{0.5}^1\frac 1{\ln(x)} \,dx \lt \int_{0.5}^1\frac {-1}{\ln(x)} \,dx$

Ergo, $\int_{0.5}^1\frac 1{\ln(x)} \,dx$ is convergent.

Comment: You shouldn't be taking the limit as $x \to \infty$. That limit doesn't mean anything for this integral with bounds $1/2$ and $1$. Also WA says [integral does not converge](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+1%2F2+to+1+of+1%2Fln%28x%29).

Comment: Why is it useless to compute that limit? Thanks for the correction of the WA result, I corrected my post. So then the integral diverges?

Comment: As $x \to 1$, $$\frac{\ln x}{x - 1} \to 1.$$ Since $\int_{0.5}^1 \frac{1}{x-1} dx$ is divergent, so is $\int_{0.5}^1 \frac{1}{\ln x} dx$ by the Limit Comparison Test for improper integrals.

Comment: You might use that limit if one of the bounds was at $\infty$. But because the bounds are at $1/2$ and $1$, the better approach is to take the limit of the ratio between $\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$ and some other function as $x$ tends to one of those two points (as in Rivers McForge's comment).

Comment: So the limit I took was the thing that lead me off? Or was there any other assumption I made that lead me astray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see that it does not converge, consider $1-\frac{1}{1-x}$. This function is greater than $\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$ for $x > 0$. And because $$\int_{\frac12}^1\left(1-\frac{1}{1-x}\right)dx$$ diverges to $-\infty$, so too does $$\int_{\frac12}^1\frac{1}{\ln(x)}dx$$

Comment: How did you come up with the function you mention? Is there something you look for? Or just keen eye?

Comment: I've seen similar problems before, but the basis was the Maclaurin series for $\ln(x)$ about $x = 1$. Because $\ln(x) = -(1-x) + O\left((1-x)^2\right)$, you could have done limit comparison with $-\frac{1}{1-x}$ in order to get the same result. I then chose to add $1$ in order to avoid the slightly messier limit comparison test and stick with direct comparison.

Comment: In general, is it all right to use Maclaurin series as bounds of the function I wish to evaluate? Or are there cases where this does not work?

Comment: It works for direct comparison only if the series is less than or greater than the original function. It's a bit more nuanced for limit comparison and depends on the ratio between the function and the series at the points in the bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Just put $u=\ln x\Rightarrow e^udu=dx\Rightarrow \int_{-\ln 2}^0 \frac{e^u}u du=\int_{1/2}^1\frac {dx}{\ln x}$. Since $e^u\ge 1/2$ over the integration range, we are essentially integrating $1/u$ close to $0$, so the integral diverges.